# How to use two statements in a trigger

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, syntax-error

I'm writing a trigger on a SQL Server 2012 table. The trigger itself is working correctly except that when I add a statement to send an email after updating a table from my trigger the ELSE statement get highlighted with an error

> Incorrect syntax near ELSE

I might have a syntax error but I can't point it out.

I've tried to add ";" at the end of line 10 and 11 but it's not doing the trick.
Commenting line 11 will make the whole trigger to work correctly

What would be the best method to have two statement/action after an IF ?

```
1 CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MembersNameToCategories ON dbo.Members
2 AFTER UPDATE
3 AS 
4 
5 BEGIN
6   DECLARE @OldName NVARCHAR(150) = (SELECT name FROM Deleted)
7   DECLARE @NewName NVARCHAR(150) = (SELECT name FROM Inserted)
8   DECLARE @BodyTXT nvarchar(MAX) = 'Customer: ' + @oldName + ' has been modified with new name : ' +@NewName + '.'
9   IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL  FROM Categories AS c WHERE c.Name = @OldName)
10      UPDATE Categories SET Name = @NewName WHERE Name = @OldName AND CategoryType = 7
11      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'MyProfile',@recipients = 'tous@mycompany.ca',@body_format = 'HTML',@body = @BodyTXT,@subject = 'A customer name has been modified'
12  ELSE
13      INSERT INTO Categories (ID,Modified,ModifiedByID,CategoryType,Name,Colour,RANK,MemberType,Private,DefaultCategory,Description,SendNotification)
14          VALUES (    
15          NEWID(),
16          GETDATE(),
17          dbo.fnmyid(),
18          7,
19          @NewName,
20          -8000,
21          9999,
22          0,
23          0,
24          0,
25          N'',
26          0
27          )
28 END;
29 GO
```

Thank you
-Martin

Comment: Add `Begin...End` block?

Comment: You need a BEGIN/END when more than one statement appears in a logical block. You can safely do `IF 1 = 1 THEN 'do stuff' ELSE 'do other stuff'`, but you need BEGIN/END if you want to do `IF 1 = 1 THEN 'do stuff' 'do more stuff' 'do even more stuff' ELSE 'do other stuff'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL  FROM Categories AS c WHERE c.Name = @OldName)
BEGIN
      UPDATE Categories SET Name = @NewName WHERE Name = @OldName AND CategoryType = 7
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'MyProfile',@recipients = 
'tous@mycompany.ca',@body_format = 'HTML',@body = @BodyTXT,@subject = 'A customer name has been modified'
END
ELSE
```